# Errors when i want to use yarn

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, yarnpkg

> **When i write in terminal** `yarn start` **, Shows this :**

```
yarn run v1.22.4
$ react-scripts start
'react-scripts' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

> **This problem starts when i installed ffmpeg.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yarn is expecting `react-scripts` to be installed in your `node_modules` directory. I suspect you either never installed it, accidentally deleted, or are running `yarn start` in the wrong directory.

To fix, make sure you're in the correct directory, run `yarn install`. After that, you should see a `node_modules` directory with `react-scripts` inside it. Then try `yarn start` again.